# How to implement a "navigation stack" in ASP.Net MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, navigation

#### Question

TL;DR: Is there a standard (or widely accepted) way to implement stack-style navigation in a web (ASP.NET MVC) application? If not, are there any patterns (or anti-patterns) I should be aware of?

#### Overview

I have an ASP.NET MVC application that shares common business entities across different areas of the application. I would like to implement a "navigation stack" feature in an ASP.NET MVC web application so that users can be sent back to any arbitrary previous "step" once they have completed a sub-step like updating one of these common entities.

For example, when filling an `Audit` form, they may first need to update an `Address` for an existing `Customer` with a new `Country`. The navigation would look like this:

```
Edit/Audit/123
-[click edit customer]-> Edit/Customer/42 // start editing customer
-[click edit address]-> Edit/Address/77   // start editing address
-[click new country]-> Create/Country     // start adding country
-[click OK or cancel]-> Edit/Address/77   // finished adding country 
-[click OK or cancel]-> Edit/Customer/42  // finished editing address
-[click OK or cancel]-> Edit/Audit/123    // finished editing customer
```

A different scenario might be to correct the address from the customer listing. The navigation would look like this:

```
List/Customer
-[click edit customer]-> Edit/Customer/39  // start editing customer
-[click edit address]-> Edit/Address/61    // start editing address
-[click OK or cancel]-> Edit/Customer/39   // finished editing address
-[click OK or cancel]-> List/Customer      // finished editing customer
```

Each add/edit/update page is a typical MVC view; we get parameters from the URL and post form data to an action on the appropriate controller. We're not using any Ajax or modal forms.

Whether the user selects `Cancel` or `Save` on a sub-step, I would like them to be returned to the previous "step" in their navigation, not just the previous page (ex: they may have posted to the same controller action multiple times already).

#### What I've considered

Simply saving the referring page doesn't work for navigating back 'down the stack'.

I was thinking of creating a stack that tracks the navigation and saves it in a session variable:

```cs
// untested code...
public static class NavigationStack
{
  public static void SaveThisPage()
  {
    var navStack = GetStackFromSession(); // gets a Stack<string> from current session
    var currentPage = Request.RawUrl;     // gets the current page URL
    
    if(navStack.Peek != currentPage)
    {
      navStack.Push(currentPage);
      SaveStackToSession(navStack);
    }
  }

  public static ActionResult ReturnToPreviousPage()
  {
    var navStack = GetStackFromSession(); // gets a Stack<string> from current session
    var prevPage = navStack.Pop();
    SaveStackToSession(navStack);

    return Redirect(prevPage);
  }
}
```

While this method seems more robust, it still feels a bit hacky b/c it requires me to call `SaveThisPage()` in every Action of every controller. It could also get quite ugly if I later need to pass additional parameters in the URL that should not be considered a new destination. Is there another way..?

Comment: I don't think there's a "standard" way of doing this. But in this example `list Customers -> edit Customer -> edit Address -> edit Customer` if you press Cancel, do you want to navigate back to `edit Address`?  That seems counter intuitive.

Comment: @Xerillio if I press `OK` or `cancel` after the second `edit Customer` I would want to return to the "bottom of the stack" `list Customers`. I was trying to show the whole sequence of navigation. I've updated the question to show this a bit more clearly.

Comment: I think you'll just have to try out something first. Saving/updating the session state in every CA doesn't seem so hacky to me. Since you're are breaking the workflow into multiple steps you'd need to keep track of every step, and that approach doesn't seem so off. An SPA (React, Angular etc.) would make this more smooth, but I have a feeling that's not an option for you.